# Will the charges in a hollow conductor feel a force from a charged body on the exterior side of the conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

Imagine a hollow conductor, and in it , lie a few point charges. On the outside, there exists a charged body. Now, will the point charges in the conductor, experience any force due to the charged body on the exterior. Will the point charges in the hollow conductor feel electrostatic forces due to their neighboring charges which all lie on the interior. How do we mathematically prove or disprove these statements?? I don't understand how. Thanks

Comment: What is the electric field of external charges inside a completely closed conductive shell? Will a single point charge inside the shell cause an electric field inside the shell? Can other charges inside the shell "feel" that electric field?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the point charges in the hollow conductor feel electrostatic forces due to their neighboring charges which all lie on the interior.

Point charges will interact with the fields of each other according to the 1/r potentials between them. It will be a many body system and needs numerical methods for solving. Proof of the statement ultimately resides on the *observational/experimental fact* that two charges interact with a 1/r potential depending on their relative charges.

> Now, will the point charges in the conductor, experience any force due to the charged body on the exterior.

No, they will not, according to [Gauss's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) and the resulting [Faraday cage effect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). [This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potsph.html) shows why.

Now laws in physics are condensed observations/data, and this law is part of the [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) which describe and predict all electric magnetic and electromagnetic situations. Laws in physics are as axioms are to mathematics. One can derive/prove them using other axioms, in this case it [can be proven by assuming instead](http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide04.pdf) Coulomb's law.

In physics ultimately the mathematical models are chosen to fit data/observations.

Comment: How do we derive the electric field inside the conductor consisting of point charges by the external body through gauss's law?

Comment: Look at page 22 here http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys1120/phys1120_sm10/lecture-notes/CH21.pdf